Asus ROG Strix RTX 4070 Ti SUPER NVIDIA PCI-e adapter small cable is cut in half. Should I be concerned?
I bought an Asus ROG Strix RTX 4070 Ti SUPER and when I opened the box and took out the NVIDIA's PCI-e express adapter that it comes with.
I put it all together and when I ran the test, the GPU Would not go past 220 Watts no matter how demanding usage was.
When usage was very high, the GPU made electrical noises. So, I started looking for problems in the adapter and this is what I saw. This is my first time with such stuff so I am not sure if this is how it should be.


Where did you buy it from? Can you test it without the adapter using your power supply? Or can you get another adapter to test it?

Return the card that cable is damaged

Yes, you should be concerned, and because this is a new computer you should return and exchange the faulty devices.

Yes, you should be concerned. Because this is new equipment you should return it for an exchange or contact the seller or company for warranty service. Cables should not be damaged like that.

That condition of the black outer sleeving makes this cable appear modified. I would suggest you return the equipment if it was sold to you as new equipment, unless you modified it. Ensure your purchases are from a reputable seller.
The GeForce RTX 4070 Ti Super reference cards include a 2x 8-pin to 12VHPWR adapter. Not all 4 of the smaller sense wires are needed. Some cables include 2 short wires that don't connect to anything purely for aesthetics, but are wrapped so the non-terminated ends don’t show. Others, such as Corsair's 12VHPWR PSU cable rated for 600W, only have 2 sense wires and leave the other connectors empty.
